# "Missing )" error

Tags: javascript

I'm working on code that asks the user for their name and age.

```
var name;
var age;

name = prompt("What is your name?");
age = prompt("What is your age?");
```

The code is setup to repeat their name and age back to them, and then it uses an if statement to either send them a message saying "You're young" if the age variable was under 50.

I have a problem, though. I can't print the string that tells that user what the age and name they inputted was. I get a syntax error that tells me there's an unexpected string.

The problem code is this:

```
console.log("You're name is " +name " and you are " +age "years old.");
```

The code works fine if I only print one variable to the console, like this:

```
console.log("You're name is " +name.);
```

Hopefully you guys can help me out.

Full code:

```
var name;
var age;

name = prompt("What is your name?");
age = prompt("What is your age?");

console.log("You're name is " +name " and you are " +age "years old.")

var printNameAndAge = function() {
    if (age>50) {
        console.log("Dang you're old.");
    }
    else {
        console.log("You're pretty young, "+name);
        alert("You're pretty young, "+name);
    }
};

printNameAndAge();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log("Your name is " + name + " and you are " + age + " years old.");
```

To insert a variable inline, you need to use the concatenation operator both before *and* after.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two `+` one after `name` and one after `age`. Please correct as below:

```
console.log("You're name is " +name + " and you are " +age+ "years old.");
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot some pluses!

```
console.log("You're name is " +name " and you are " +age "years old.");
```

should be

```
console.log("You're name is " +name +" and you are " +age+ "years old.");
```